# Find a generator for an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

> Let $I$ be the ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$ generated by $L=\{T^{2}-1, T^3-T^2+T-1,T^4-T^3+T-1\}$. Find $f\in\mathbb{Q}[T]$ such as $(f)=f\mathbb{Q}[T]=I$.

The book solution proves that $I\subseteq (T-1)$ and $(T-1)\subseteq I$.

Could I take the following approach as well?

As $f=T-1$ divides all the polynomials in $L$ and by definition

$\left<L\right>=\{h \mid h= g_{1}(T^{2}-1) +g_{2}(T^3-T^2+T-1) +g_{3}(T^4-T^3+T-1), g_{i}\in\mathbb{Q}[T]\}$

so $f$ divides any $h$ in the above set and hence it generates $I$.

Comment: You can try Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: You have only proved $I \subset (T-1)$, but the reverse inclusion is needed too. For example, the polynomial $1$ divides all the polynomials in $L$, but it's not true that $I = (1) = \mathbb{Q}[T]$.

Comment: @jjjx, i guess that you write T instead of X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $I=\langle L\rangle$ and $T-1$ divides all polynomials in $L$ you get that every polynomial in $I$ is a multiple of $T-1$, that is, $I\subseteq (T-1)$. (This is the part you proved.)

Conversely, we have to show that $(T-1)\subseteq I$, that is, $T-1\in I$. You know that the elements of $L$ are in $I$ and let's use them to show that $T-1\in I$: $$T^2-1=(T+1)(T-1)\in I$$ $$T^3-T^2+T-1=(T^2+1)(T-1)\in I$$ $$T^4-T^3+T-1=(T^3+1)(T-1)\in I$$ and $$(T^3+1)-T(T^2+1)+(T+1)=2,$$ so $2(T-1)\in I$ and since $2$ is invertible we get $T-1\in I$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ I\!:\ \color{#c00}{T^2\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \begin{array}{}0\equiv \color{#c00}{T^2}T\!-\color{#c00}{T^2}\!+T\!-1\\ \ \ \equiv \color{#c00}{1}\cdot T-\color{#c00}1\, +\,T-1\\ \ \ \equiv 2\,(T\!-\!1)\, \Rightarrow\, T\!-\!1\equiv 0\ \Rightarrow\ T\!-\!1\in I\end{array}$